# Typing Russian characters in vim with vim-LaTeX

Tags: options, plugin-vim-latex

Occasionally, I need to type documents in Russian in LaTeX format. To use Russian in vim I follow the guidelines from this [Habr post](https://habr.com/ru/post/98393/). In short, I have the following settings in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenmac
set iminsert=0
set imsearch=0
highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Cyan
```

With these settings in place I can use `Ctrl+^` to switch between English and Russian languages in vim insert mode. For convenient typing of LaTeX commands in vim I use the [Vim-LaTeX distribution](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-latex/). The configuration commands relevant to vim-LaTeX in my `.vimrc` are:

```
" envoke LaTeX-Suite on TeX file open
filetype plugin on

" load filetype-specific indent files
filetype indent on

" load vim-latex for empty TeX files
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

All is nice and well and I’m satisfied with this setup. However, there is one small problem that makes my life miserable. One of the Russian letters, the small letter «ю», is not typed correctly. When I press the relevant key on the keyboard I get a full stop symbol «.» instead of the small letter «ю». On the other hand, the capital letter «Ю» (when pressing the Shift key) is produced correctly. Would you please be so kind to help me debug the problem? Maybe I have some option clashes with the vim-LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Try to replicate issue with clean vim

1. `vim --clean`
2. `:set keymap=russian-jcukenmac`

If you are able to enter letter ю, something is wrong with your vimrc

### 2. Check what is in your keymap file

Open `:e $VIMRUNTIME/keymap/russian-jcukenmac.vim` and find letter `ю`. Make sure it is correctly mapped:

```
.   ю   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YU
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It works with `vim --clean` and `:set keymap=russian-jcukenmac`. I will investigate my `.vimrc` file now.

Comment: Do binary search with the help of `:finish` command. Just put it in the middle of your vimrc, then in the middle of the first or last half, etc.

Comment: I fixed it! The order of loading the Russian keymap and vim-LaTeX settings was wrong. Now I set Russian keymap first and the vim-LaTeX commands last.

Comment: @mabalenk Consider posting that last part about the ordering between langmap and the vim-latex settings as an additional answer. It might help others with the same or similar problem in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I have modified the `~/.vimrc` file in the following manner:

1. Load Russian language specific keymap first and
2. Set vim-LaTeX options last, i.e.:

   ```
   " Russian language {{{
   " ----------------
   set keymap=russian-jcukenmac
   set iminsert=0
   set imsearch=0
   highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Cyan
   " }}}

   ...

   " vim-latex {{{
   " ---------
   " envoke LaTeX-Suite on TeX file open
   filetype plugin on

   " load filetype-specific indent files
   filetype indent on

   " load vim-latex for empty TeX files
   let g:tex_flavor='latex'
   " }}}
   ```